# Exporting a layer loses its transforms

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a layer in photoshop that I want to shrink (scale down by 50%), then export as a PNG.

Right now if I click the layer, transform it, then export it, the exported PNG is not scaled down.

What should I do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Photoshop exports it uses the **canvas bounds** as the defining area, *not* the visible pixels.

I suspect you have a whole lot of transparent pixels around your smaller layer (50%) image. If you want to export visible pixels your canvas needs to be the size of the visible pixels.

There are a couple ways to do that:

- Use `Image > Image Size` to resize the image (canvas) rather than transforming a layer.
- After transforming a layer, use `Image > Trim > Transparent Pixels` to remove all the left over canvas.

If the goal is to keep the existing document canvas at it's current size you can copy the transformed layer to a new document, then use the `Image > Trim` operation on the new document.

Comment: Thanks Scott - very informative answer!  Are "canvas bounds" layer specific, or for my entire image?

Also any ideas `Image > Trim > Transparent Pixels` would be disabled in my file?

Comment: If you have no transparent pixels, it'll be disabled. You might find `Image > Trim > Top Left Pixel Color` may work better. Or remove the background layer - the goal being to have only what you want exported visible, no other layers.